# Swift - Concurrency issue when loading search result. I load the images, send the requests, but the requests are too late

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

So I have an app that loads movie search results from the web live as the user types. I throttle my search requests so that it only reloads once every 0.3 seconds. (This probably isn't relevant at all, but what the hell). Now my problem is this.

1 - I type in a search term, let's say "Search1". In order to save time, I load up each result's title, year and genre instantly (almost). I keep the poster black, and send an asynchronous request to load the image, because it takes a lot more time. I wait for the image to load.

2 - Before the images load, I then type in another term, let's say "Search2". So I get the text results for "Search2", and maybe some images.

3 - But then the old requests for "Search1" start rolling in, and they replace those of Search2, because they loaded slower. What I get is a combination of old and new images because I couldn't cancel the old requests.

How should I solve this? I need a way to tell the device to stop loading the old images if the user started typing again, and I can't cancel asynchronous requests. How do I fix this?

**Code:**

- The cell throttling stuff

  func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

  ```
  // to limit network activity, reload 0.3 of a second after last key press.
  NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget(self, selector: "reload:", object: searchController)

  if (!UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible) {
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
      self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
  self.performSelector("reload:", withObject: searchController, afterDelay: 0.3)
  }
  ```
- Here is the code that loads up each cell's info:

  ```
      override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as! CustomCell

      //Safe-Guard. This shouldn't be needed if I understood what I was doing
      if (indexPath.row < matchingItems.count) {
          cell.entry = matchingItems[indexPath.row] //404

          /*
          .
          .
          omitted code that loads up text info (title, year, etc.)
          .
          .
          */

          //Poster
         cell.poster.image = nil
          if let imagePath = matchingItems[indexPath.row]["poster_path"] as? String {
              //Sessions and Stuff for request
              let url = NSURL(string: "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + imagePath)
              let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
              let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

             //Asynchronous Code:
              let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                  if let poster = UIImage(data: data!) {
                  //I want to stop this piece from running if the user starts typing again:
                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                          //Animate the poster in
                          cell.poster.alpha = 0.0     // hide it
                          cell.poster.image = poster  // set it
                          UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
                              cell.poster.alpha = 1.0 // fade it in
                          }
                      }
                  }
              })

              dataTask.resume()

          } else {
              //Just use placeholder if no image exists
               cell.poster.image = UIImage(named: "Placeholder.jpg")
          }
      }

      return cell
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future people stuck with the same issue, I used [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), a networking library that allows you to cancel asynchronous requests. If you use Objective-C then look up AFNetworking. It's the same thing but for Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the indexPath of the cell and see if it's the same or if it's been dequeued and reused for another another row.

```
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if let poster = UIImage(data: data!) {
                //I want to stop this piece from running if the user starts typing again:
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        //Animate the poster in
                        if tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) == indexPath {
                            cell.poster.alpha = 0.0     // hide it
                            cell.poster.image = poster  // set it
                            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
                                cell.poster.alpha = 1.0 // fade it in
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: Yes but this is a hack not a solution. :/ I can also check if the cell's id # is still the same, but this can still crash if, for example, the indexPath doesn't exist anymore. I want a way to rewrite my code. I know this is hard, I've thought about this a lot. I just can't find a solution.

Comment: This is standard UITableViewCell behavior. On what line will it crash? `indexPath` is guaranteed to not be nil. `tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)` could be nil, but so what, it will just cause `if tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) == indexPath` to evaluate to false which is what you want in that cause.

Comment: Ok, I think this may stem from my misunderstanding of what an indexPath is. I've seen the documentation for [NSIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSIndexPath) but I still don't understand. If this is checking if we're still at the same cell (Let's say #4) then it might coincide that the image result for cell4 in search1 loads for cell4 in search2, so it reloads over search2's image result right? Am I missing something?

Comment: I should have said this is more of an example of something you can do. In general, you need to check the state of the cell and see if it still matches the state you set in the beginning of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Many developers use indexPath matching, but it may not work for your situation. Just use some unique identifier. You can use the movie title for example, unless there are some with the same title.

Comment: Yeah... there are. See, all of these solutions are fixes. I did find a way, though. I downloaded and used Alamofire. Alamofire allows me to cancel asynchronous requests. So it works now. Thanks, for your help though

Comment: Obviously, you can us NSURLSession (or some third-party wrapper) and cancel requests. However, it is very common to do some asynchronous loading on reusable views and compare state. It's odd to consider this a "hack." There are lots of reasons you might not want to cancel requests, particularly on a mobile device with limited data, for example if the loaded data might be useful in the future it would to let the request finish and cache. That being said, glad you found a good solution.